# Is there a more elegant way to find gem root than Gem::Specification.find_by_name?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a more elegant way of finding a gem's root than this?

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name('gem-name').gem_dir
```

Comment: This is pretty elegant already. How more elegant could it get?

Answer (score 1):

```
gem list <gem> -d

Or if you're using bundler:

bundle show <gem>
```